# Having trouble getting calls to addChild() on nested children in vanilla ActionScript 3 to do anything

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics

Assume the following code:

```
package 
{
    import somenamespace.Button;

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public final class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main()
        {           
            stage ? init() : addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            function init(pEvent:Event = null):void {
                // support autoOrients
                stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
                stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
                removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);


                /*var btn:Button = new Button(0, 0, 400, 400)
                addChild(btn);*/

                var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
                sprite.width = 400;
                sprite.height = 400;
                addChild(sprite);



                var label2:TextField = createCustomTextField(sprite, 0, 50, 200, 20);
                label2.text = "Drag to select some of this text.";
            }
        }

        private function createCustomTextField(sprite:Sprite, x:Number, y:Number, width:Number, height:Number):TextField {
            var result:TextField = new TextField();
            result.x = x; result.y = y;
            result.width = width; result.height = height;
            sprite.addChild(result);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble getting nested children to show their own children on the screen.  `addChild()` presumably adds the child, but nothing happens on the screen.  I don't understand why.  I'm used to using Flex and Starling and stuff like that, but the idiom seems to have changed a bit on even this basic point when going to straight vanilla.

You can see where I've commented out a bit of code where I was designing a custom button class, and I was having a lot of the same trouble with it; however I was able to get it to finally draw a blue rectangle on the screen, once I stopped trying to add a sprite to that effect to the button, and once I started to use the button's own `graphics` property to draw the rectangle instead (`Button` extends `Sprite`), along with using some awkward timing and such when manipulating its width and height.

Earlier I was trying to add the `TextField` directly to the `Button`, originally within its own constructor, but even adding it to a regular `Sprite` in the `Main` class isn't working.  Replacing `sprite.addChild(result);` with `addChild(result);` makes it show up fine though.

In general, what's wrong with this type of design?  I'm not just asking about this particular example, but in general, how do you get children to add children that add children and so on?  Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Well, as it turns out, setting the `width` and `height` on a `Sprite` is what's causing the problem.  Take that out, and you're fine.  You can even make that nested `Sprite`'s `graphic` property draw a rectangle of a certain width and height, and then add children to that `Sprite`, as long as you are not actually setting those particular properties.  Obey this one rule, and everything works great.  Disobey, and it's the *end of the world!!!*

...Or is it?  I mean, those properties are probably there for a valid reason; it's just hard to tell why they would be linked to causing issues like preventing children from showing up on the screen, for no other reason than the simple fact that you touched them.  As I experimented, I usually made sure the values provided for a size that was plenty big enough for any of the `Sprite`'s children, and that their `x` and `y` properties were also set appropriately, so they shouldn't have just been moved offscreen or even off the `Sprite` itself.  Anybody got an idea?

**EDIT**

One other thing to note is that, once I got the `Button` class to draw a blue rectangle, I was somehow able to adjust the size of the rectangle itself by setting the `width` and `height` properties of the `Button`; the `Button`'s `graphics` property was having its size scaled to align with the `Button`'s, and this was part of a built-in algorithm.  However whether that actually worked or not depended on things being set up a certain way, and that setup itself seemed kind of random.  At this point, I'm moving forward just fine without messing with `Sprite`s' `width` and `height` properties, but there was something there that was kind of obscure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things I'd suggest here - take a look at this:

```
package com.test
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            //Change the stage parameters
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            //Adding a test Sprite
            var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
            this.addChild(sprite);

            //Adding some color to the sprite so you can see ti
            sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000,1);
            sprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 200);
            sprite.graphics.endFill();

            //Adding a text field
            var textField:TextField = new TextField();
            textField.text = "HELLO!";
            this.addChild(textField);

        }   
    }
}
```

Here's a similar example that'll hopefully show what's going on. First, your init function is being called in the constructor so I'm not sure if that'll work like it should, try pulling it out into its own function. Also - display objects when instantiated don't actually have anything in them so there's really no need to specify height and width. Let the contents determine the height and width unless you some need to define them explicitly.

You can modify the example so that the TextField is added to the sprite instead of the main Sprite by using:

```
sprite.addChild(textField);
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Let's first find out what the documentation says about the width property:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#width

> The width is calculated based on the bounds of the content of the display object.

There's no content in a newly created Sprite object. It is just an empty container.
Reading this value without content makes sense, the answer is 0. But writing a value to it that's different from 0 doesn't make too much sense.
How do you want to change the width of nothing?

Basically speaking, an empty DisplayObject should not have a writeable property width.
Maybe it should throw an error when you try to do it, but it doesn't really have to, because the operation isn't very logical.